# PHP parse error T_FOREACH

Tags: php, foreach, syntax-error, parse-error

I am trying to create table in PHP using array but I am getting parse error in my foreach line. Don't know why its giving me syntax error.

```
$message = '<table border=1>
        <tr>
        <th><b>Order Details</b></th>
        </tr>

        '.foreach ($json_array->request->list as $value) {
            $wineId = $value->wineId;
            $wineName = $value->wineName;
            $noOfDrinks = $value->noOfDrinks;
        .'

        <tr>
          <td>ID</td><td>'.$wineId.'</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Name</td><td>'.$wineName.'</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Quantity</td><td>'.$noOfDrinks.'</td>
        </tr>
        '. } .'
      </table>';
```

Comment: You can't put a foreach in a string like that.

Comment: Then how can i do this? Can you please guide me. I am not expert in php as I am Java guy so not comfortable with php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, use string concatenation except php code

```
$message = '<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th><b>Order Details</b></th>
    </tr>';

    foreach ($json_array->request->list as $value) {
        $wineId = $value->wineId;
        $wineName = $value->wineName;
        $noOfDrinks = $value->noOfDrinks;


   $message .= '<tr>
      <td>ID</td><td>'.$wineId.'</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Name</td><td>'.$wineName.'</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Quantity</td><td>'.$noOfDrinks.'</td>
    </tr>';
       }
  $message .='</table>';
```